# How to choose kqueue flag EV_ONESHOT or EV_DISPATCH?

Tags: kqueue

In `kqueue` it's possible to submit a `kevent` with `EV_ONESHOT` or `EV_DISPATCH` flags. The first *deletes* the `kevent` after first event delivery, and the latter *disables* the `kevent` after first event delivery.

The observable effect with both flags is that subsequent events will not be delivered unless the `kevent` is re-added or re-enabled, respectively.

Are there other observable effects between `EV_ONESHOT` and `EV_DISPATCH` and how to choose one over the other?

The manual page for disabling a `kevent` using `EV_DISABLE` mentions that *The filter itself is not disabled.* Then, if I choose to use `EV_DISPATCH`, the filter itself is not disabled. I don’t understand what effect that has. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question after having done more research.

I recommend reading the 2001 USENIX paper *"Kqueue: A generic and scalable event notification facility”* at [http://people.freebsd.org/~jlemon/papers/kqueue.pdf](http://people.freebsd.org/%7Ejlemon/papers/kqueue.pdf).

When kernel receives a `kevent` from user, it creates a `knote` to represent the subscription and a filter to deal with the event source. The filter is invoked on event source activity such as packet arrival or signal delivery. The `knote` is added to an active list for event delivery to user if the filter indicates so and the `knote` is enabled. This is enough to understand the difference between `EV_ONESHOT` and `EV_DISPATCH`.

`EV_ONESHOT` causes the `knote` and the filter to be deleted after first event delivery. Thus the filter can no longer be called on event source activity. `EV_DISPATCH` causes the `knote` to be marked disabled after first event delivery, but the filter will remain to process event source activity. Whether this is a meaningful difference depends on the filter being used. Additionally, enable/disable is a faster operation than add/delete. The USENIX paper has some graphs on the performance.

I wrote a program (tested on macOS) to demonstrate the difference using `EVFILT_SIGNAL`. Maybe someone will find this useful in the future.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/event.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        struct timespec timeout = {.tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 0};
        sigblock(sigmask(SIGUSR1));
        pid_t pid = getpid();
        int kq = kqueue();
        struct kevent e;

        EV_SET(&e, SIGUSR1, EVFILT_SIGNAL, EV_ADD | EV_ENABLE | EV_DISPATCH, 0, 0, NULL);
        // EV_SET(&e, SIGUSR1, EVFILT_SIGNAL, EV_ADD | EV_ENABLE | EV_ONESHOT, 0, 0, NULL);
        kevent(kq, &e, 1, NULL, 0, NULL);
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        kevent(kq, NULL, 0, &e, 1, &timeout);
        printf("%jd\n", e.data);

        // When EV_DISPATCH is used, the filter continues to record
        // event source activity. When EV_ONESHOT is used, there is no
        // longer a filter to record activity. In either way, kernel
        // doesn't deliver events to user.
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);

        EV_SET(&e, SIGUSR1, EVFILT_SIGNAL, EV_ADD | EV_ENABLE, 0, 0, NULL);
        kevent(kq, &e, 1, &e, 1, &timeout);

        // Prints 3 or 0 with EV_DISPATCH or EV_ONESHOT, respectively.
        printf("%jd\n", e.data);
        close(kq);
}
```